# Why rails does an error 500 in production when it doesn't find an image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I tried to add some images to test some pages. In a loop, I call images which don't exist yet (and maybe will never exist! I don't know if my user will give us an image or not).

I was waiting to just have an broken image on heroku, as in my local dev environnement. But it looks like I have a big error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (tmptodelete/icon6.png isn't precompiled):
```

So now, I cannot access to my online page because rails which cannot load an image generate...a 500 error! It looks really overreacting!!

My question is how can I prevent against this comportement?

I don't want that my server produces an error 500 because an image is missing...

Comment: Please improve your question by posting some [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) code that is relevant to your error message.

Comment: What server are you using?

Comment: Hello, I use heroku. Here is a pastebin (which is down right now) of my error: http://chopapp.com/#jjnkhxhy